# Why do Mathematica and Wolfram|Alpha say $\Gamma(-\infty)=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, gamma-function, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

According to Mathematica and Wolfram|Alpha, $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\Gamma(x)$ is equal to zero. See e.g https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma+function (at the bottom of the page), or try `Limit[Gamma[x], x -> -Infinity]` on Mathematica.

This contradicts the fact that $|\Gamma(x)|$ can be arbitrarily large when x is close enough to any negative integer.

Is Mathematica and Wolfram|Alpha wrong on this, or is there any other way to interpret this result?

Comment: What version of M'ma are you using?  M'ma 11.3.0.0 leaves `Limit[Gamma[x], x -> -Infinity]` unevaluated.

Comment: This is right, and it is technically wrong to say that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \Gamma(x) = 0$. However, you can notice that the as $x \to -\infty$, the poles at the negative integers get steeper and steeper, and in between negative integers you can notice that the Gamma function gets closer and closer to zero. A statement like the following should be true: "for every $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and $\delta > 0$, there exists some $N$ such that every $x < N$ which is at least $\delta$ away from the closest negative integer has $|\Gamma(x)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: @paulinho : So ... you're saying that as $x \rightarrow -\infty$, $\Gamma(x) \rightarrow 0$ (in some version of) in measure?  Specifically, $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \mu\left((-\infty, x) \cap \{t \in \Bbb{R} : |\Gamma(t)| > \varepsilon\}\right) = 0$.

Comment: @EricTowers I think that statement may be true, but I'm not ready to claim something as strong. What I'm willing to say is that 
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \mu(([x], [x] + 1) \cap \{t \in \mathbb{R}: |\Gamma(t)| > \epsilon\}) = 0$$
for all $\epsilon > 0$ (where $[ ~ ]$ denotes the floor). The difference is that this could still allow for something like 
$$\mu(([x], [x] + 1) \cap \{t \in \mathbb{R}: |\Gamma(t)| > \epsilon\}) \sim \frac{1}{|[x]|}$$
which would imply
$$\mu((-\infty, x) \cap \{t \in \mathbb{R}: |\Gamma(t)| > \epsilon\}) = \infty$$
for all $x$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ is a continuous variable, then $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \Gamma(x)  $ does not exist.

But if  $-\infty$ is approached in a discrete manner, then the limit might exist.

For example, let's replace $x$ with $N+ \frac{1}{2}$, where $N$ is an integer.

The reflection formula for the gamma function states that $$\Gamma(x) = \frac{\pi \csc(\pi x)}{\Gamma(1-x)} $$ for all $x \notin \mathbb{Z}. $

Therefore,  $$ \lim_{N \to - \infty}\Gamma \left(N + \frac{1}{2} \right) = \lim_{N \to -\infty} \frac{\pi \csc \left(\pi \left(N + \frac{1}{2} \right) \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-N \right)} = \lim_{N \to -\infty} \frac{\pi \sec \left(\pi N \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-N \right)} =0 $$ since $\sec (\pi N)$ is just bouncing between $1$ and $-1$, while $\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-N \right)$ is going to infinity.

EDIT:

In fact, as long as you stay greater than some fixed distance away from the negative integers, the limit will seemingly be zero.